# getting field attribute tags using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, postsharp

This is my program

```
<code>
 [demosapect]
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=xx;User ID=sa;");
</code>
```

i am using these code as

```
foreach (FieldInfo targetfield in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.ExactBinding ))
  {

// here i need to list out those attributes......
}
```

i need to list out the attribute name [demoaspect] through reflection!

Waiting for your response......

Answer (score 0):

use this code as

```
if (targetfield.GetCustomAttributesData().Count > 0)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(targetfield.GetCustomAttributesData()[0].ToString());
                }
```

It solves my query!!!!!!!!